# SQL time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make it more efficient? What I am trying to do is get 6 months period split back from 2020-08-31 to 2022-08-31, is there a way to calculate the time periods automatically, without listing them like the below as it is very manual.

```sql
select case when date between '2022-03-01' and '2022-08-31' then '1 Mar 2022 to 31 Aug 2022' 

    when date between '2021-09-01' and '2022-02-28' then '1 Sep 2021 to 28 Feb 2022' 
    when date between '2021-03-01' and '2021-08-31' then '1 Mar 2021 to 31 Aug 2021' 
    when date between '2020-08-31' and '2021-02-28' then '31 Aug 2020 to 28 Feb 2021' 
        ELSE 'prior 31 Aug 2020'
         END as Time_period
```

Comment: I have _assumed_ you are using SQL Server here. If you are using a different product that you can connect to using SSMS, such as Azure SQL Database, or Azure Synapse, please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: The logic seems broken, data from 2022-09-01 is going to show up under `'prior 31 Aug 2020'`. Also I don't know how you could do _all_ of this automatically, since most of your periods start on the 1st of the month, but one starts on the last day of the month (and so is 6 months + 1 day, not 6 months). How can SQL Server automatically know that 2020-08-31 is a special case?

Comment: only when you have algorithm that could determinr which dates are the limit , you maybe could write some dynamic sql, but that would defeat the purpose

Comment: DECLARE @date date = '2022-08-31' 

case WHEN date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @date) THEN '1 Mar 2022 to 31 Aug 2022' 
 WHEN date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @date) THEN '1 Sep 2021 to 28 Feb 2022' 
 WHEN date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -18, @date) THEN '1 Mar 2021 to 31 Aug 2021' 
 WHEN date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -24, @date) THEN '31 Aug 2020 to 28 Feb 2021' 
              ELSE 'prior 31 Aug 2020'
           END as Time_period

----do you reckon that would work better?

Comment: the data prior 2022-09-01 may under 'prior 31 Aug 2020' but it will not be included in the final results, I will exclude it at end for anything 'prior 31 Aug 2020'.

Answer (score 1):

It's peculiar to include August 31st 2020 in statement as it breaks the other patterns. If we use Sep 1 2020 as the bottom, then here's an alternate method, but I don't think it's any better than what you're already doing. Perhaps slightly easier to read and repeat.

```
create table my_data (
  id integer, 
  some_date date
  );
```

```
insert into my_data (id, some_date) values 
(1, '2019-01-01'), 
(2, '2020-04-02'), 
(3, '2020-09-02'), 
(4, '2021-01-01'), 
(5, '2021-02-28'), 
(6, '2021-03-01'), 
(7, '2021-08-31'), 
(8, '2021-10-28'), 
(9, '2022-01-15'), 
(10, '2022-07-01'), 
(11, '2022-11-02');
```

```
select id, some_date, 
  case
   when datediff(month, '2020-09-01', some_date) < 0  then 'Prior to 01 Sep 2020'
   when datediff(month, '2020-09-01', some_date) < 6  then '1 Sep 2020 to 28 Feb 2021'
   when datediff(month, '2020-09-01', some_date) < 12 then '1 Mar 2021 to 31 Aug 2021'
   when datediff(month, '2020-09-01', some_date) < 18 then '1 Sep 2021 to 28 Feb 2022'
   when datediff(month, '2020-09-01', some_date) < 24 then '1 Mar 2022 to 31 Aug 2022'
  end as time_period
from my_data
where some_date < '2022-09-01'
```

| id | some_date | time_period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | Prior to 01 Sep 2020 |
| 2 | 2020-04-02 | Prior to 01 Sep 2020 |
| 3 | 2020-09-02 | 1 Sep 2020 to 28 Feb 2021 |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 | 1 Sep 2020 to 28 Feb 2021 |
| 5 | 2021-02-28 | 1 Sep 2020 to 28 Feb 2021 |
| 6 | 2021-03-01 | 1 Mar 2021 to 31 Aug 2021 |
| 7 | 2021-08-31 | 1 Mar 2021 to 31 Aug 2021 |
| 8 | 2021-10-28 | 1 Sep 2021 to 28 Feb 2022 |
| 9 | 2022-01-15 | 1 Sep 2021 to 28 Feb 2022 |
| 10 | 2022-07-01 | 1 Mar 2022 to 31 Aug 2022 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D5CUxBqY)

Comment: thank you so much this is much easier to update, appreciate it

Comment: If you find this acceptable then please consider marking as Approved.